# How do you perform a django lookup between different applications using the same database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following class (reduced down for brevity):

```
from other.app.models import Enclosure

class Server(models.Model):
    enclosure = models.ForeignKey(Enclosure, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name='server_enclosure')

    def get_enclosure(self):
        get_enclosure = self.enclosure.server_enclosure.get(rack=10)
```

models.ForeignKey(Enclosure <-- Enclosure is a class in separate app.

Question I have is on the query. I suspect this is not that proper way to to do this since pylint-django complains. Is there a better way within django to perform the get()?

I was looking at the django docs, and it looks like the information for lookups that span relationships is tailored towards models within the same application. I can't seem to find any good reference pattern for lookups that span different applications using the same database.

Comment: I think this is totally ok. if I got it in right way:) For example multiple projects could have `auth` app with users, and other apps that have models related to user. So such cross app lookup are needed. because you will want to filter something by user in one app, do some filtering in another.

Comment: Thank you. You definitely did get it in the right way :-). Issue I am having is pylint-django keeps throwing a no-member error, so just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: It's completely untrue that relationship lookups are meant for the same application only. Django simply doesn't care which apps your relationships are in.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DanielRoseman. I think the issue I had was more around finding examples that demonstrate best practices. Everything I found online was based on classes contained within the same module/file. I had a feeling django didn't are on the apps, I just needed a reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will handle cross-application and even cross-database joins for you.  However, it will be up to the application developer / DevOps to make sure that the cross-database joins are actually doable (e.g., by housing the two databases within the same MySQL or PostGRES instance).  However, the code that you have looks relatively funky.  To get the server enclosure with rack=10, I would do the following:

```
from other.app.models import Enclosure

class Server(models.Model):
    enclosure = models.ForeignKey(Enclosure, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name='server_enclosure')

    @classmethod    
    def get_enclosure(cls):
        return cls.objects.get(rack=10)
```

To get the enclosure related to a particular server, you can just use:

```
p = Server.objects.get(...)
enclosure = p.enclosure
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks 2ps for the feedback.